# Erro de excessão ao autenticar login com valores nulos - Simplemembership - ASPNET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu desenvolvi um projeto em asp.net mvc5 de um curso que eu estou fazendo,  que esta acusando o seguinte erro de excessão na hora de autenticar o menu de login quando não insiro nenhum dado nos campos de formulario e passo parametros nulos:

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   WebMatrix.WebData.dll but was not handled in user code - Additional
>   information: Value cannot be null or an empty string"

Eu acredito que o problema seja com o simplemembership, porque nas outras views de formulários quando eu autentico com valores nulos não acontece este erro de excessão, sendo que o controller do menu login foi configurado com o simplemenbership. Eu gostaria de saber como é que configura o simplemembership para não dar este erro de excessão quando autentica com valores nulos. Segue abaixo o print da tela e o codigo do logincontroller[image: print da excessão]

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace Financas.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Autentica(string login, string senha )
        {
               if (WebSecurity.Login(login, senha))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movimentacao");
            }
               else
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("Login.Invalido", "Login ou senha incorretos");
                return View("Index");
            }
            }
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, como a mensagem diz, este método não aceita valores nulos nem **strings vazias**. Neste caso você teria que validar diretamente seus valores desta forma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace Financas.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Autentica(string login, string senha )
        {
             if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(login) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(senha)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Login.PreencherTodosCampos", "Por favor, preencha todos os campos.");
                return View("Index");
            }


             if (WebSecurity.Login(login, senha))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movimentacao");
            }
               else
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("Login.Invalido", "Login ou senha incorretos");
                return View("Index");
            }
            }
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");



        }
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço.

Comment: Eu modifiquei e deu certo aqui no meu projeto, obrigado.